# Running repeated tasks in php

Tags: php

I am using the following code to get some info from a website and save it locally.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://test.com/test.txt");
$fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Now the test.txt needs to be updated periodically. How can I trigger this at specific time intervals?

Comment: use cron my son

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on *nix or a Mac (or even Cygwin), you're probably better off using wget:

```
@hourly wget http://test.com/test.txt
```

That will do everything that cURL call will do, and do it on an hourly basis. Here's a good cron intro: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto